# Archaic conjugation of common verbs?

Tags: verbs, tenses, archaicisms, conjugation

I'm looking for an online resource to list conjugation of some of most common English verbs (*to be, to get, to do, to have* etc.) in their archaic (Early Modern) forms. In particular, I'd be interested in conjugation for various tenses - I can easily find "am, art, is, are" and similar, but finding conjugation of "did" is not nearly as easy.

Comment: For samples, just read some Shakespeare.

Comment: see here: https://theweek.com/articles/441478/tis-season-archaic-english

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't found a convenient resource, but there's really not much to say:

**be**

- *I am*
- *thou art*
- *he, she, it is*
- *we, ye, they are*
- *I, he, she, it was*
- *thou wast*
- *we, ye, they were*

**have**

- *I, we, ye, they have*
- *thou hast*
- *he, she, it hath*
- *I, he, she, it, we, ye, they had*
- *thou hadst*

**do**

- *I, we, ye, they do*
- *thou dost*
- *he, she, it doth*
- *I, he, she, it, we, ye, they did*
- *thou didst*

Almost all other verbs are like *do* and *have*, with three forms in the present (*eat*, *eatest*, *eateth*) and two in the past (*ate*, *atest*). Sometimes the 'e' is omitted giving endings *-st* and *-th*. This is regular in the past (eg *waitedst*, and even the tongue-twister *walkedst*), and sporadically elsewhere, especially in poetry.

**Edit**: added the sentence about omitting the 'e'

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Could you add "get" to the set yet?

Comment: No different, except for the doubling of the 't' (regular, as in _getting_, _getter_ etc): _gettest_, _getteth_, _gottest_.

Comment: *thou gotst* for past?

Comment: @SF *Gottest* ... but *got'st* was the ordinary contraction. "Where got'st thou that goose look" -*Macbeth*

Comment: @StoneyB: you're right. I've just added a note that the 'e' is usually syncopated in the past. _Gotst_ it is, though I'm sure _gottest_ occurs as well.

Comment: Don't forget that spelling was not standard before printing. Peepl speld thingz however they liket, mosly bicaus they wurr recording there acshal speech. So whether an E was used or not was a matter of personal choice, not spelling rule. Like handwriting is today; how you form a letter is your business, and nobody cares.

Comment: If Wiktionary gets it right, it should be "thou wast". "Thou wert" was the subjunctive form, to which "thou beest" would be the present tense equivalent.

Comment: You're right, @user112758. Now corrected.